# Cant install wine on ubuntu 17 (broken packages error)

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, dpkg, dependencies

http://tipsonubuntu.com/2017/07/23/wine-2-13-released-install-ubuntu/
i followed all the instructions in this tutorial yet it wont install, i keep getting this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-devel : Depends: wine-devel (= 2.22.0~artful)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

i also tried 'sudo apt-get -f install' but it still wont work. 
help?

Comment: did you enable multiarch? WINE requires 64-bit and 32-bit packages.

Comment: do you mean  ia32-libs?

Comment: @ravery You mean _disable_ it? Multi-arch is enabled by default for a long time now, on 64-bit builds.

Comment: Actually, it looks like a problem with the WineHQ archive. You should possibly discuss it with the Wine devs on their site.

Comment: I mean enable it - WINE needs i386 packages.  what is the result of `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` ?